# Discontinuities of function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If    $f(x) = \begin{cases}
x,x\in[0,1],\text{ $x$ is rational} \\
-x,x\in[0,1],\text{ $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases} $
  then
a)All discontinuities of $f$ in $[0,1]$ are of the first kind.
b)All discontinuities of $f$ in $[0,1]$ are of the second kind.
c)$f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.
d)$f$ is discontinuous at all points of $[0,1]$. I am confuse whether $f$ is continuos at $0$ or not?According to me $f$ is continuous only at $0$.Please correct me and what will be it's correct option?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_n\to 0$. We have $|f(x_n)|=x_n\to 0=f(0)$ so that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

All discontinuities are of the second kind because the left and right limits of $f(x)$ as $x\to a$ do not exist for any $a\in(0,1]$.